# Applying compression on multipage TIFF

Tags: wia

I have the following code which takes a `List` of `WIA.ImageFile` and creates a multipage TIFF from those files:

```
Function MakeTiff(images As List(Of Object))
    Const wiaFormatTIFF = "{B96B3CB1-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
    Dim ip = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WIA.ImageProcess")
    Dim frameFilterID = ip.FilterInfos("Frame").FilterID
    For i = 2 To images.Count
        ip.Filters.Add(frameFilterID)
        ip.Filters(i - 1).Properties("ImageFile") = images(i - 1)
    Next
    ip.Filters.Add(ip.FilterInfos("Convert").FilterID)
    ip.Filters(ip.Filters.Count).Properties("FormatID") = wiaFormatTIFF
    Return ip.Apply(images(0))
End Function
```

How can I compress the resulting TIFF file (assuming it's not compressed already)?

Comment: Check this post - [WIA: no compression when saving files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508974/wia-no-compression-when-saving-files)

Comment: @Rachel I've seen it already. I'm generating a multipage TIFF file, not a JPEG. Or does that not make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using wia 2.0 settings:

```
.Properties("6146").Value = 1    '4 is Black-white,gray is 2, color 1
.Properties("6147").Value = 200  'dots per inch/horizontal
.Properties("6148").Value = 200  'dots per inch/vertical
.Properties("4107").Value = 5    '0 = NONE, JPG = 5, PNG = 8 *WiaCompressionMode
```

Its works in VB.net and VBA, compress arround 98%